# Git: How to use subfolder of a repository as submodule?

Tags: git

**1. The situtation**
Let's say I have a repository with the following folder structure:

```
repo1\
|
|-Foo\
|-Bar\
```

**2. The Requests**
- In a second repo `repo2` I want to use `repo1` as submodule; but only the contents of the folder `Foo\`. 
- Whenever someone clones `repo2` and initializes the submodule, automatically (or only with reasonable effort) there should be only the folder `Foo\` present in the submodule folder.

**3. What I have tried**
- Sparse checkout as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28039894/4958965) does not work with submodules at all, at least as far as I managed to make it work 
- Filter branch as indicated [here](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Adding-a-folder-from-one-repo-to-another/td-p/5425) or [here](http://alyssafrazee.com/2014/05/01/popping-a-subdirectory.html) works for me fine; but whenever someone clones `repo2` the procedure must be repeated for their clone

**4. The Questions** 
- How can I make that work?
- What else should I try?

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert `repo1/foo` into separate independent repository
2. Add *this* repo as submodule to repo1|repo2

You'll have some headache on intersection of a "split point" for any direction, but... it's fair price for possibility to use *now* as you want

Comment: If I do a commit in ```repo1```, how will I be able to pull the update into the submodule?